# Where can I see operator overloads of primitive types by using ILSpy?

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading, clr, mscorlib

Just out of curiosity I was trying to find the relevant operator overloads for unary operators like +,-,* etc. for Int32 in MsCorLib.dll

I use ILSpy.

When I checked the System.Int32 struct definition, I could not see any operator overloading related.

**Q:** Do I look at the wrong place -then where should I look to see operator overloads for primitive types- or I should not even expect to see those methods?

Comment: The operator overloads are not documented on MSDN either, which makes me suspect that they are not part of the BCL, but built into the C# compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operators are part of C# and defined in the [C# Language Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029).

*Example:*

> **7.7.2 Unary minus operator**
>
> *[...]* The predefined negation operators are:
>
> - Integer negation:
>
>   ```
>   int operator –(int x);
>   long operator –(long x);
>   ```
>
>   The result is computed by subtracting x from zero.  *[...]*
> - Floating-point negation:
>
>   ```
>   float operator –(float x);
>   double operator –(double x);
>   ```
>
>   The result is the value of x with its sign inverted. If x is NaN, the result is also NaN.
> - Decimal negation:
>
>   ```
>   decimal operator –(decimal x);
>   ```
>
>   The result is computed by subtracting x from zero. Decimal negation is equivalent to using the unary minus operator of type System.Decimal.

Comment: So you propose I should use MS Word instead of ILSpy? :) I have seen that in ths CLS Specs but I am curious to spot it -if possible- in the mscorlib.dll

Comment: You won't spot the operators in any assembly. Primitive types receive special treatment from the compiler. For example, if you add two `int` values, the compiler does not emit a `call` instruction to invoke an operator method that computes the result, but an `add` instruction that computes the result directly.

Comment: So it is the compiler what handles those operators on primitives not the primitive type definitions? Right?